# call another actionresult from controller with multiple parameters netcore mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, redirect, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a method (MethodA) in my controller that needs to return another `ActionResult` (methodB) in that same controller, with some parameters as payload. For this I use a `RedirectToAction(nameof(methodB), new { param1=param1, param2=param2 } )` at the end of MethodA.

When I debug, all the parameters are loaded and contain the expected values. However when it arrives at methodB, the two parameters are empty.

MethodA

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Bulkimport(int id)
{
    int customerId = 5;
    ReturnModel returnMessage = new ReturnModel();
    returnMessage.Message= "All data loaded";
    returnMessage.returnModel = returnModel; //contains list with some data
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Bulkimport), new { id = customerId, model = returnMessage });
}
```

MethodB

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Bulkimport(int id, MessageModel model)
{

    // Do stuff, but MessageModel and id are null.
    return View();
}
```

Does anyone have an idea what might be happening here?
Additional: I have some experiences that additional parameters are presented in the receiving view as a querystring in the url in the browser. Is there any way to prevent it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
return RedirectToAction(nameof(Bulkimport), new { id = customerId, model = returnMessage });
```

To

`````
return Bulkimport( customerId, returnMessage);

````
`````

Comment: Thank you. Sometimes it can be so simple :)